# In .NET Core, why would I decide to create a library that targets .NET Standard rather than .NET Core?

Tags: .net-core

What would be the advantage of targeting .NET Standard and what would I be missing if I chose to target this over .NET Core?

Comment: Same advantage as targeting PCL in the olden days.  Portable class libraries are usable in multiple projects.  If you pick .netcore then it can only be used in an app that targets .netcore as well.  Disadvantage is the same as well, not as many classes and methods are supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you target .NET Standard, you would have an assembly that's compatible with every platform that implements .NET Standard. So .NET 4.5 and up, .NET Core, UWP, Mono, etc.

If you target .NET Core, you get more than just the API's defined in the standard (the standard, for instance, doesn't define any UI stuff, so that's extra in .NET Core), but then your assembly would only be compatible with .NET Core.

In other words, if you want maximum portability, choose .NET Standard. If you want more features and only need to support the .NET Core implementation, choose .NET Core.